# PHP Error - syntax error, unexpected 'extends' (T_EXTENDS)

Tags: php, syntax-error, extends

Working on a school assignment with PHP. I get an immediate error after the

syntax error, unexpected 'extends' (T_EXTENDS)

Sample Code is below, any help is appreciated.

```
<?php

@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Welcome to Your Feed</div>
                    <div class="card-body">
{{--                         <form method="post" action="{{route('users.update', Auth::user())}}">

                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                            {{ method_field('patch') }}

                            <input type="text" name="name"  value="{{ Auth::user()->name }}" />
                            <input type="email" name="email"  value="{{ Auth::user()->email }}" />

?>
```

Comment: What environment are you running this in? Is it Laravel? If so, which version?

Answer (score 2):

You may try to remove the <php and ?> tags. The code inside is not a valid PHP script...

It's some framework obviously. Probably you should fetch an example page and build on it at the beginning before you get comfortable with it.

Comment: That's right, `@` is also a silence operator in php and `extends` gets interpreted as php function(which it isn't) when found inside a <?php ?> scope.